# How to randomise my menu items?

Tags: array, php

So I thought I could do it like this (also I want to only get 3) -

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items(26);
$menu_items = array_rand($menu_items, 3);

foreach ( (array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) {
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    echo $title;
}
```

Comment: So: Did you do it? How did it work out? What _is the Q_?

Answer (score 1):

Ehm, *afaik* the `return` value of the menu fn is an `object`: You need to `type cast` earlier

```
$menu_items = (array) wp_get_nav_menu_items( 26 ); // Typecast here
$menu_items = array_rand( $menu_items, 3 );

foreach ( $menu_items as $key => $menu_item ) 
{
    echo $menu_item['title'];
}
```

Comment: No this didn't work.

Comment: See update/edit. Slight misstake on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the return of the menu function is an array of objects.

For some reason, the array_rand only returned an array of the IDs, so this is what I did:

```
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu_slug');
$menu_items_rand = array_rand($menu_items, 3);
$random = array();
foreach($menu_items_rand as $ran)
    $random[] = $menu_items[$ran];

print_r($random)
```

You don't want to destroy the `$menu_items` array, because you'll need it in the foreach.